# Código de estado: 404 not found angular 8 JSON

Tags: json, angular

I had a project in Angular 8:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Smartphone } from 'src/app/others/interface';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-http',
  templateUrl: './http.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./http.component.sass']
})
export class HttpComponent implements OnInit {
  smartphone: any = [];
  httpdata: string;
  headers: HttpHeaders;
  nombre: string;
  primerApellido: string;
  segundoApellido: string;
  existeRespuesta: boolean;
  parametros: HttpParams;
  localUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/smartphone';
  localUrl2 = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
  form: FormData;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.getSmartphones6();

}
getSmartphones() {
  this.existeRespuesta = true;
  // Muestra los datos del json tanto por html como en la consola
  this.http.get(this.localUrl, {responseType : 'json'})
  .subscribe(data => this.displaydata(data));
}

getSmartphones1() {
  this.existeRespuesta = false;
  // envia los parametros en la peticion
  this.http.get(this.localUrl, {responseType : 'json',
      headers : {
      'content-type' : 'application/json'
      },
      observe: 'body',
      params: {
        id: 'P0001',
      },
      reportProgress : true

   })
  .subscribe(data => this.displaydata(data));
   }
 displaydata(data: any) {
   console.log(data);
   this.httpdata = data;


   if (this.existeRespuesta === false) {


   /* this.parametros = new HttpParams();
   this.parametros.set('nombre', 'pedro');
   this.nombre = this.parametros.get('nombre');
   this.primerApellido = this.parametros.get('primerApellido');
   this.segundoApellido = this.parametros.get('segundoApellido');
   console.log(this.parametros.get('nombre'));*/
   }
}
getSmartphones2() {
  this.http.get(this.localUrl, {responseType : 'json'})
  .subscribe(data => {
    for (const d of (data as any)) {
      this.smartphone.push({
        name: d.name,
        price: d.price
      });
    }
    console.log(this.smartphone);
  });
}
getSmartphones3() {
 this.form = new FormData();
 this.form.append('archivo', 'archivo');
 this.http.post(this.localUrl, this.form , {
 headers : {
  'content-type' : 'multipart/form-data'
           }
  })
.subscribe(data => this.displaydata(data));
}

getSmartphones4() {
  this.http.delete(this.localUrl, {
    params: {
      id : '001'
    }
  });
}

getSmartphones5() {
  this.http.patch(this.localUrl, {
    nuevonombre : 'javier'
    }, {
    params: {
      id : '001'
    }
  });
}

getSmartphones6() {
  this.http.delete(this.localUrl, {
    headers : {
      'content-type' : 'application/json'
      },
      observe: 'body',
      params: {
      id: 'P0001' } // el servidor ya sabe que tiene que borrar el movil con esa id
    })
    .subscribe(data => this.displaydata(data));
}

}
```

and a JSON:

```
 {
  "smartphone": [
    {
      "id": "P0001",
      "name": "iPhone X",
      "desc": "iPhone X 128GB Internal Memory, 8GB RAM, 6 Inch IPS Display",
      "price": 499,
      "updated": "Wed Sep 20 2019 17:22:41 GMT+0700"
    },
    {
      "id": "P0002",
      "name": "iPhone 11 Pro",
      "desc": "Super Retina XDR display, 5.8‑inch (diagonal) all‑screen OLED Multi‑Touch display, HDR display, 2436‑by‑1125-pixel resolution at 458 ppi 2,000,000:1 contrast ratio (typical)",
      "price": 699,
      "updated": "Wed Sep 20 2019 17:22:41 GMT+0700"
    },
    {
      "id": "P0003",
      "name": "iPhone XR",
      "desc": "Liquid Retina HD display 6.1-inch (diagonal) all-screen LCD Multi-Touch display with IPS technology 1792-by-828-pixel resolution at 326 ppi 1400:1 contrast ratio (typical)",
      "price": 599,
      "updated": "Wed Sep 20 2019 17:22:41 GMT+0700"
    },
    {
      "id": "PVE964J"
    },
    {
      "id": "VLbUIIg"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

When I execute my project and when I log in http://localhost:4200/ can I have 404 when I execute

```
this.http.delete(this.localUrl, {
        headers : {
          'content-type' : 'application/json'
          },
          observe: 'body',
          params: {
          id: 'P0001' } // el servidor ya sabe que tiene que borrar el movil con esa id
        })
        .subscribe(data => this.displaydata(data));
    }

}
```

Comment: what if you put the id as a path param `this.http.delete(this.localUrl + '/P0001', ...)`

Comment: can you  describe your REST API for delete smartphone?

Comment: It works with this.http.delete(this.localUrl + '/P0001').subscribe(); thanks